# Hibernate Envers AuditQuery is adding _id to mappedBy column and is failing with exception "can not resolve property"

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Envers to audit my entities. But when I use the AuditQuery to fetch the revisions of my entity along with the associated entity, it fails with the following exception:

```
could not resolve property: userid_id of: com.envers.domain.vo.UserOrgVO_AUD [select e__ from com.envers.domain.vo.UserOrgVO_AUD e__ where e__.userid_id = :userid_id and e__.originalId.REVISION_ID.id = (select max(e2__.originalId.REVISION_ID.id) from com.envers.domain.vo.UserOrgVO_AUD e2__ where e2__.originalId.REVISION_ID.id <= :revision and e__.originalId.id = e2__.originalId.id) and REVISION_TYPE != :delrevisiontype]
```

My entities are as follows:

***User(id: Long, name: String, organisations: Set[UserOrganisation])***

***UserOrganisation(id: Long, userid: Long, organisation: Organisation)***

***Organisation(id:Long, name: String)***

The VO classes are defined as follows

**UserVO**

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
@Audited
public class UserVO {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Audited
  private List<UserOrgVO> organisations;

  /**............................................................

     constructors, getters and setters ....

     ............................................................*/
}
```

**UserOrgVO**

```
@Entity(name = "USER_ORGANISATIONS")
@Audited
public class UserOrgVO {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column (name = "USER_ID")
  private Long userid;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "ORGANISATION_ID", nullable = false)
  private OrganisationVO organisation;

  @Column (name = "PREFERRED", nullable = false)
  private boolean preferred = false;

  /**............................................................

     constructors, getters and setters ....

     ............................................................*/
}
```

**OrganisationVO**

```
@Entity(name = "ORGANISATIONS")
@Audited
public class OrganisationVO {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false, name = "NAME", length = 70)
  private String name;

  /**............................................................

     constructors, getters and setters ....

     ............................................................*/
}
```

The function that tries to fetch the revisions of a user is as follows

```
@Override
public List<UserVO> findAllRevisions(Long id) {
  AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
  AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(UserVO.class, true, true);
  query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id));
  List revisions = query.getResultList();

  List<UserVO> users = new ArrayList<>();
  for(Object rev : revisions) {
    UserVO userRev = (UserVO) rev;
    for(UserOrgVO userOrgRev : userRev.getOrganisations()) {
      System.out.println("user org id: " + userOrgRev.getId());
    }
    users.add(userRev);
  }

  return users;
}
```

The line **userRev.getOrganisations()** in the above function throws the following exception

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userid_id of: com.envers.domain.vo.UserOrgVO_AUD [select e__ from com.envers.domain.vo.UserOrgVO_AUD e__ where e__.userid_id = :userid_id and e__.originalId.REVISION_ID.id = (select max(e2__.originalId.REVISION_ID.id) from com.envers.domain.vo.UserOrgVO_AUD e2__ where e2__.originalId.REVISION_ID.id <= :revision and e__.originalId.id = e2__.originalId.id) and REVISION_TYPE != :delrevisiontype]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userid_id of: com.envers.domain.vo.UserOrgVO_AUD
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1764)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:505)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:660)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:204)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:104)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:942)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1283)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4696)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4166)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2131)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2056)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2056)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:810)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:605)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.query.AbstractRelationQueryGenerator.getQuery(AbstractRelationQueryGenerator.java:55)
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.AbstractCollectionInitializor.initialize(AbstractCollectionInitializor.java:49)
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.checkInit(CollectionProxy.java:33)
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.iterator(CollectionProxy.java:57)
at com.envers.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.findAllRevisions(UserServiceImpl.java:79)
```

Can you tell why envers is adding "_id" to the column "userid" in UserOrgVO and how to correct it?

Thanks & Regards,

Sarath

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your mappings.

You are attempting to define a bi-directional mapping between `UserVO` and `UserOrgVO` but the problem is you're only specifying the `@OneToMany` side and not specifying the `@ManyToOne` who owns it.

I assume the reason behind doing this is likely an optimization to prevent Hibernate from attempting to fetch and load the `UserVO` object when you loaded `UserOrgVO` entities in other parts of your code but this isn't the correct way to handle that.

Technically your mappings should be as follows

```
public class UserVO {
  ...
  @OneToMany(
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
    mappedBy = "user", 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
    orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<UserOrgVO> organizations;
}

public class UserOrgVO {
  ..
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  private UserVO user;
}
```

You'll notice I mapped `user` in `UserOrgVO` as `FetchType.LAZY`.  This means that Hibernate should create a proxy for you based on the value from the `USER_ID` column and will only fetch and hydrate the `UserVO` instance when its getter is first called; thus making it truly lazy.

If you truly want the `userid` to also be mapped as a property you can access on the `UserOrgVO` entity, you can do that by duplicating the `USER_ID` column in the `UserOrgVO` entity as follows:

```
@Column(name = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long userid;
```

The caveat here is that anytime you change the `user` property in `UserOrgVO` to reference a difference user object, you should update the `userid` value so that it remains consistent in the persistence context.  When it comes to the database, Hibernate will only set the value based on what `UserVO` entity is associated and completely ignores the value in `userid`.

In short, you can think of `userid` as a transient value that Hibernate sets the entity is loaded from the database and otherwise does absolutely nothing with it.  It's purely informational from that point forward.